# Dell laser printer printing washed out colours that rub off the page

Tags: printing, printer, laser-printer, toner

I have a Dell c1760nw that I've been successfully using with compatible cartridges most of it's service life, but I'm an occasional printer and over the last few years I've noticed the pages are getting progressively patchy/washed out, to the point where the toner now rubs off if you apply enough pressure.

I've tried re-setting the printer back to defaults, increasing the fuser temperature and changed the toner cartridges to new ones.

I'm unable to get any spare parts for this printer so I'm almost certain it's ready to be recycled, but just wanted to check if there was any additional steps I could try before purchasing a new printer.

[image]

Comment: Fuser probably dying. You can't get into Dell's service area properly without a service tag, but maybe see https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-uk/product-support/product/dell-c1760nw/docs

Comment: Have you tried the troubleshooting and maintenance topics described in the manual? https://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_printers_main/esuprt_printers_color_laser/dell-c1760nw_user%27s%20guide_en-us.pdf - this is a cheap printer. Apart from the maintenance and troubleshooting, it’s time to replace it otherwise.

Comment: I have tried the troubleshooting, along with a few forum post suggestions to no avail. However I did try printing full black documents around 20 times, which caused it to pause halfway through with "refreshing" on it's screen, and when it resumed, the black was very dark with no washed out colour. Every print since then is becoming fainter though - what would this be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Tetsujin is correct: the Fuser is a heating element that melts the toner (which is a plastic of some sort), fusing it to the paper.

If the toner is still powder it is not melting and therefore the heating element (the fuser) is not working correctly.

It is plausible that your paper is too thick, insulating or absorbing heat, but if you are using standard thickness paper, this is not the problem.

If the first few sheets are OK and then they get bad, then the Fuser cannot generate heat fast enough to keep up with the print speed. Again, probably the Fuser. Heavier paper is more of a heat sink so again, it may be a cause if your paper is too think.

Most or many printers have the Fuser separate from the toner cartridge. It is usually one of the more expensive replacement parts.

Note that powdered toner is very fine particulate and can potentially cause e.g. cancer or fibrosis in the lungs even if "inert" chemically (*any* super-fine powder inhaled is dangerous, regardless of chemical composition and toner is very close or under to 10 microns).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wonder if you can help with one more query. I have improved the quality by printing 10's of entire black sheets which vary in quality, but far better than the original image I posted. I'm not sure why but text now prints pretty well and adheres to the paper normally but when printing any large block of solid black, it's patchy like my original photo but no longer rubs off! Would this still point in the direction of the fuser, or is this normal laser printer behaviour? https://imgur.com/a/HPu4qBL Also notice the two vertical lines. Appreciate your reply!

Comment: White lines or spots (the absence of toner) is probably going to be the result of paper fibers or debris build-up on the image drum. Great care (and research about methods) should be taken if you attempt to clean the drum.